# Return index of smallest number instead of smallest number

Tags: python

How do I make my code return the index of the smallest number rather than just the smallest number? This is what I've written:

```
def index_smallest(first):
minimum = first[0]
for x in first:
    if x < minimum:
        minimum = x
return minimum
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `return minimum` to `return first.index(minimum)`.

Or use

```
def index_smallest(first):
    return first.index(min(first))
```

Demo:

```
>>> first = [1, 0, -1, 3]
>>> first.index(min(first))
2
```

Comment: caveat: for super mega long lists or if you want to process millions of lists, the solutions which only have to loop over the list once instead of twice (in the worst case) are superior.

Comment: Not necessarily; approaches like this one get to do the looping internally in C, rather than by evaluating Python bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

For this just iterate over the available indices rather than the items in the list. You can do this by making a `range()` iterable object based on the length of the list. Then you change all occurrances of x to be first[x] instead or grab the item each time like so:

```
def index_smallest(first):
    minimum = first[0]
    min_index = 0
    for i in range(len(first)):
        x = first[i]
        if x < minimum:
            minimum = x
            min_index = i
    return min_index
```

There's a more efficient way to do this, but your way works well enough.

Answer (score 1):

This method uses `emuerate()` to provide the index of each item. It requires only *one pass* over the sequence. It returns the index of the first item with the minimum value, or `None` if the sequence is empty.

```
from operator import itemgetter

def index_smallest(seq):
    value = itemgetter(1)
    try:
        return min(enumerate(seq), key=value)[0]
    except ValueError as exc:
        return None

>>> index_smallest('') is None
True
>>> index_smallest([10, 20, 1, -10, 32])
3
>>> index_smallest((i for i in [10, 20, 1, -10, 32]))    # generator expression
3
>>> index_smallest('qwerty')
2
>>> index_smallest(iter('qwerty'))
2
```

This will also work with sequences that do not support subscripting, e.g. generators. It's debatable whether the position of an item in a spent generator is of any use, but I suppose there might be some use case for a finite generator. This code will handle all iterables and it will not blow up if an empty sequence is passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple occurrences of smallest number. In which case, this will return the first occurrence.

```
def index_smallest(numList):
    return numList.index(min(numList))
```

Answer (score -1):

what you could do first is take the list of numbers and find the largest member.
Then after that you can use the .index() method to obtain the corresponding index.
For example:

```
my_numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
greatest_number = max(my_numbers)
greatest_number_index = my_numbers.index(greatest_number)
print(greatest_number_index, greatest_number)
```

Comment: OP wants the index of the _minimum_ value, not the maximum.

Comment: sorry I was just giving an example, all OP would want to do is swap max for min.